# Understanding Persistent Connections for Custom Push Notification Services in Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, telegram

I am currently conducting research on the implementation of custom push notification services in Android applications.

I am particularly interested in understanding how to create a persistent connection in Android, similar to the tgnet connection used by Telegram, to connect to a custom push server. My goal is to develop a deeper understanding of how such a connection can be maintained without being closed by the Android system, even when the app is not in the foreground. This seems to be a key feature of Telegram's notification system, and I am curious about how it could be implemented in a custom push notification service.